# npm script to concat json files with key as file name

Tags: json, npm, gruntjs, concatenation, npm-scripts

Does anyone know an npm script to concatenate multiple json files with keys as file name.

example

fileone.json

```
{
  "john": "doe"
}
```

filetwo.json

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

output I want:

concat.js

```
{
  "fileone": {
     "john": "doe"
   },
  "filetwo": {
     "foo": "bar"
   }
}
```

There are couple of grunt tasks that accomplish this, but I am refraining myself from adding another task runner in my project.

npm concat-cli is primarily built to concat javascript files so if used for json the resulting file is incorrect.

So if anyone knows a good solution here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know an npm script to concatenate multiple json files with keys as file name?

**Short answer** - There are no existing solutions to handle this that I'm aware of.

---

#### Solution

To avoid using another task runner, such as `grunt`, you could consider utilizing your own custom node script to handle this requirement. Then simply invoke the node script via your `npm-script`

The following example gist shows how this can be achieved...

---

**concat.js**

The custom node script is as follows:

```js
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

// Default destination path for resultant json file.
var destPath = path.join(__dirname, 'result.json');

// Default no console logging.
var verbose = false;

// Nice ticks for logging aren't supported via windows cmd.exe
var ticksymbol = process.platform === 'win32' ? '√' : '✔';

var jsonFilePaths = [];
var concatenatedJson = {};

// Create a readline interface ( https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html )
// to read each path piped via the glob pattern in npm-script.
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: null,
  terminal: false
});

// Handle the optional `-o` argument for the destination filepath.
if (process.argv.indexOf('-o') !== -1) {
  destPath = path.join(__dirname, process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('-o') + 1]);
}

// Handle the optional `-v` argument for verbose logging.
if (process.argv.indexOf('-v') !== -1) {
  verbose = true;
}

/**
 * Get the json filename for use as json key.
 * @param {String} filepath - The filepath to the source json file.
 * @returns {String} The json filename without file extension (.json).
 */
function getKeyFromFileName(filePath) {
  return path.basename(filePath, '.json');
}

/**
 * Obtain the contents of the source .json file.
 * @param {String} filepath - The filepath to the source json file.
 * @returns {String} The json content.
 */
function readJsonFile(filePath) {
  return fs.readFileSync(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });
}

/**
 * Create a new json/object using filename as key for files content.
 * @param {String} filepath - The filepath to the source json file.
 */
function concatJson(filePath) {
  var key = getKeyFromFileName(filePath),
    json = readJsonFile(filePath);

  concatenatedJson[key] = JSON.parse(json);
}

/**
 * Save the resultant concatenated json file.
 * @param {String} filepath - The filepath to save the resultant json file.
 * @param {String} content - The json content to save to file.
 */
function saveFile(filePath, content) {
  fs.writeFile(filePath, content, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    if (verbose) {
      console.log(ticksymbol + ' Successfully created: ' + destPath);
    }
  });
}

// Read each line from process.stdin
// I.e. Each json filepath found via the glob pattern in npm-script
rl.on('line', function(filePath) {
  jsonFilePaths.push(filePath);
});

// When readline closes begin processing json files and write
// the resultant concatenated json data to disk.
rl.on('close', function() {
  jsonFilePaths.forEach(function (filePath) {
    concatJson(filePath);
  });

  saveFile(destPath, JSON.stringify(concatenatedJson, null, 2));
});
```

---

**npm-scripts**

You can invoke the `concat.js` script via your `npm-script` like this:

```json
"scripts": {
  "concat": "glob \"path/to/**/*.json\" | node concat"
},
```

***Note:*** [cli-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-glob) is used to specify a glob pattern to find the source `.json` files to concatenate. So you'll need to install that:

`$ npm i -D cli-glob`

The glob pattern, the part that reads `"glob \"path/to/**/*.json\"`,  finds all the `.json` files to concatenate beforing piping them to the `concat.js` script. This glob pattern will need to be redefined as per your project directory structure (I.e. to wherever your source `.json` files are located).

---

**Additional Notes**

1. The `npm-script` gist above assumes that `concat.js` has been saved in your projects root directory (i.e. the same level as your `package.json`). You can of course save it elsewhere you'll just need to define the path to it in `npm-scripts` accordingly. For example, lets say you save it in an invisible folder named `.scripts` which resides in your projects root directory, then you would define your `npm-script as follows:`

```json
   "scripts": {
     "concat": "glob \"path/to/**/*.json\" | node .scripts/concat"
   },
```

2. By default the resultant/concatenated `.json` file is saved to a file in the projects root directory named `result.json`. However, an optional `-o` argument can be provided in your `npm-script` to define an alternative destination path. For example; to save the resultant file to a file named `quux.json`, in your projects root directory, then the `npm-script` would be defined as follows:

```json
   "scripts": {
     "concat": "glob \"path/to/**/*.json\" | node .scripts/concat -o quux.json"
   },
```

3. The resultant `.json` file can also be save to subfolder in the projects root directory. For example lets say you want to save the results in a file named `foobar.json` to a folder named `build` in your projects root directory then configure your `npm-script` as follows:

*(Note: The destination folder/folders must exists as `concat.js` does not create them for you. However, that functionality could be added)*:

```json
   "scripts": {
     "concat": "glob \"path/to/**/*.json\" | node .scripts/concat -o build/foobar.json"
   },
```

4. `concat.js` by default does not confirm successful completion of concatenating `.json` files. To log a completion message to the console showing the path to where the file was saved include the `-v` option/flag in your `npm-script` for example:

```json
   "scripts": {
     "concat": "glob \"path/to/**/*.json\" | node .scripts/concat -v -o build/foobar.json"
   },
```

Running `$ npm run concat` *(using the last configuration shown)* would log something similar to this in your console upon completion:

> `✔ Successfully created: /Path/to/myProject/build/foobar.json`

Hope this helps!